# User status message for iOS chat app

Tags: iphone, xmpp, chat, openfire, xmppframework

I am developing an iPhone chat application using robbiehanson/XMPPFramework and I am using OpenFire on the server side. I want to implement the user status feature on my app like the whatsapp status concept.

How can I achieve this, is there any default support on the openfire server for storing the user status messages ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you call 'user status'. You can add information about the presence of the user in presence packets. This is purely transient information and is generally not stored in XMPP server.

You can also decide to publish status information in a more persistent way using Personal Eventing Protocol (PEP). The last status is generally stored by server to be resend / retrieved at a later time.

Reference: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html

Comment: On whatsapp when we are visiting someone others profile we can see their status like busy, work etc. or other custom status. Whatsapp call them as user current status. Similarly on my application I want to include a feature to set the user status and it should be visible to all others.

Comment: Sure, but in XMPP, this types of features can be handled by several difference specifications. I engage you to have a look at the two approaches I mention.

Comment: Mickaël I have doubt, suppose I will send my mood/activity using PEP, then is it will be stored in the openfire or robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for later retrieval(by default) ? Or we need to manually implement the storing mechanism ?

Comment: PEP items are stored by Openfire as it need to be able to resend them.

Comment: ok...in my app a user account have fields like - username, first name, last name, image, emailID, and user current status. So when I am updating them the IQ or the vCard  should be updated to reflect all these changes on the user account?

Comment: I need to upate the user IQ or vCard ? or anything else for updating the user information on the XMPP

Comment: Well, IQ is a packet type. You do not "update" it, so I guess you want to update vcard.